# how to fetch all data from one table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join

i have following tables in mysql database

a_ad_display

```
id | advId |
```

a_mediatype

```
id | mediaId
 1 | animation 
 2 | Video
 3 | Image
```

a_advertise

```
advId | mediatypeId | organizationId
```

now what i want is to get all records of advId from a_ad_display with the count of advId which is register with organizationId="some particular id " in advertise table and group by with their media type.

i have achieved this with the following query ....

```
SELECT COUNT(a.advertiseId) as Total ,m.medianame

FROM a_mediatype as m

 JOIN a_advertise as a ON a.mediaTypeId = m.mediaId

 JOIN  a_ad_display as ad ON ad.advId = a.advertiseId

where a.organizationId in(SELECT t.organizationId

FROM organization_ AS t JOIN organization_ AS p ON  t.treePath LIKE CONCAT( p.treePath, '%')

where p.organizationId ='37423')  GROUP BY m.medianame
```

but my ouput comes like this

```
  medianame | count 
  animation | 92
  Images    | 103
```

so it means that there is no video type advId in a_ad_display with the some particular organoization Id...

but what i want is like as follows...

```
medianame | count 

animation | 92

video     | 0

Images    | 103
```

it means if there is no advid from particular mediatype then also shows that in output with the 0 Count..

any one can give me some guidance in this problem?

**see my sql fiddle demo**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/391a2/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT 
  m.medianame,
  IFNULL(COUNT(ad.id), 0) AS Total 
FROM a_mediatype as m
LEFT JOIN a_advertise   AS a   ON a.mediaTypeId    = m.mediaId
LEFT JOIN a_ad_display  AS ad  ON ad.advId         = a.advId
LEFT JOIN organization_ AS o   ON a.organizationId = o.organizationId
LEFT JOIN organization_ AS p   ON o.organizationId = p.organizationId 
                              AND p.organizationId = '37423'  
                              AND o.treePath       LIKE CONCAT( p.treePath, '%')
GROUP BY m.medianame;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5faf8/2)

This will give you:

```
| MEDIANAME | TOTAL |
---------------------
| animation |    13 |
|     image |     2 |
|     video |     0 |
```

Comment: i had tried this..but its not working...same result is given after this query..i thought i will solve with left join but don't know why its not working

Comment: nope its not working..i dont want to change this line :- where a.organizationId in(SELECT t.organizationId

FROM organization_ AS t JOIN organization_ AS p ON  t.treePath LIKE  CONCAT( p.treePath, '%')

where p.organizationId ='37423')

Comment: @BhavikKama - I didn't change it, I rewrite it using joins. But this what makes your query works as inner join not `LEFT JOIN` can you please show some sample data for the other three tables, it will be very helpful.

Comment: but its giving unknown collumn error..ok.w8 give u sample data

Comment: @BhavikKama It was that column in the `JOIN` I fixed it. See my edit.

Comment: can we please continue to chat ? this is the error i got :- Unknown column 't.organizationId' in 'on clause'.i replaced with o.organizationId which gave me wrong result

Comment: @BhavikKama OK, but I don't know why it removed from here. Can you please show some sample data from these three tables. Or set up a demo in [this site](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26606/discussion-between-mahmoud-gamal-and-bhavik-kama)

Comment: @BhavikKama - Sorry for late, I was busy, ON work right now. See my edit, it is the same query but I fixed the columns' names. Not sure whether the output is correct or not.

Comment: no the ouput is not correct....i checked..and now check with my old query...the output came is correct..but with no row with video

Comment: @BhavikKama Sorry again, try `IFNULL(COUNT(ad.id), 0) AS Total` instead. See my edit.